# Issue: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///home/tonton/.docker/desktop/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, local, daemon, ubuntu-22.04

Hello Guys when I run `docker version`
My docker compose version is : docker compose version
Docker Compose version v2.2.2

```
 Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           20.10.18
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.18.6
 Git commit:        b40c2f6
 Built:             Thu Sep  8 23:11:43 2022
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           desktop-linux
 Experimental:      true
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///home/tonton/.docker/desktop/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

I am using ubuntu 22.04 version.

Comment: Is the docker daemon really running? Try to run `systemctl status docker` or `ps -ef | grep dockerd` to check if there is a `dockerd` process running.

Comment: Yes it is active and running

Comment: When i use sudo docker version everything is ok but when i try to run without sudo it is not working

Comment: This is normal behavior. If you want to have docker access as a non-root user, you should follow these steps: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/#manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user. But beware! Basically by doing this, you're decreasing security.

Comment: I had follow this instruction but still not working

Comment: Did you logout and re-login ? You will not belong to `docker` group until you login again.

Answer (score 8):

In my case:

- I had installed docker desktop by apt in ubuntu20.04 before, but removed it later .
- And when I try to check `sudo docker images` today there is the same issue.
- Restarting docker, chown socket and some other strange ways don't work.
- Suddenly I discover that there is no such socket file in docker/desktop/, but in the default location /var/run. Then trying to restore docker default context by `docker context use default` makes everything come back to normal.

So I think that the remained docker-desktop context takes the responsibility.....

Comment: 1 hour pulling my hair, and finally found this. You made my day, thank you so much.
This answer should be accepted by author. Voting it up meanwhile.

Comment: `docker context use default` cleared the error for me on Ubuntu 22.04.2.  I also had installed Docker Desktop, but wasn't using it; I think Desktop must set the context to `desktop-linux` automatically.

Comment: I can confirm that this was indeed the case for the error. For me, the error started showing the day I installed docker-desktop on ubuntu 22.04. The command `docker context list` shows you the available contexts and the location of  .sock.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted /home/user/.docker/* and it solved my problem. Probably I had reinstalled all but not I did not delete the old configuration.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).